# Rythm. render() throws exception while generating an xml file

Tags: xml, rythm

I am trying to generate an xml file using Rythm template and I get the `org.rythmengine.utils.TextBuilder` build() error when I add an `@if()` condition with a `@for()` loop.

```
@if(errorObjs != null) {
  <Errors>
  @for(ErrorObject errObj : errorObjs) {
     <Error>
        <ErrorCode>@errObj.errorid</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorMessage>@errObj.errorcode</ErrorMessage>
     </Error>
  }
  </Errors>
}
```

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of the error stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your template try the code below at:

http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor

The issue might be in your Java Code.

```java
@def class ErrorObject {
  String errorid;
  String errorcode;
  public ErrorObject(String id,String code) {
     errorid=id;
     errorcode=code;
  }
}
@{
  List<ErrorObject> errorObjs=new ArrayList<ErrorObject>();
  errorObjs.add(new ErrorObject("id1","code 1"));
  errorObjs.add(new ErrorObject("id2","code 2"));
  errorObjs.add(new ErrorObject("id3","code 3"));
}
@if(errorObjs != null) {
  <Errors>
  @for(ErrorObject errObj : errorObjs) {
     <Error>
        <ErrorCode>@errObj.errorid</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorMessage>@errObj.errorcode</ErrorMessage>
     </Error>
     }
 </Errors>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the question, just a comment about the usage of the `@if`:

if you want to check if something is `null` go directly with:

`@if(errorObjs) {
   // display the errors
}`

See more about `@if` directive at http://rythmengine.org/doc/directive.md#if

Another suggestion about the code is container object like `List` shall always be non-null value, instead of return `null` for container, return empty container to make your code be much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer. And I guess the answer provided by @wolfgang-fahl below should be accepted instead. And you might hit the "up" for my answer ;-)